# How to convert Json to CSV in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, csv

Hi I am trying to convert a json file with differrent array structure than the normal one into csv file. I had been trying to find out a solution to convert it into a csv file but I cant find the solution.

```
  <?php 
    $jsondata = '[{
        "accession_number_original": "2012.11.45",
        "author_birth_date": [
          "1932"
        ],
        "author_date": [
          "1932"
        ],
        "author_death_date": [
          ""
        ],
        "author_description": [
          "American"
        ],
        "author_display": [
          "Day yon"
        ],
        "author_names_first": [
          "Day"
        ],
        "author_names_last": [
          "yon"
        ],
        "author_names_middle": [
          ""
        ],
        "image_height": "12 1/2",
        "image_width": "18 1/4",
        "jp2_image_url": "",
        "location_physical_location": "Art Gallery",
        "location_shelf_locator": "Unknown",
        "master_image_url": "",
        "note_provenance": "Gift of Gary Ginsberg and Susanna Aaron",
        "object_date": "1963/2010",
        "object_depth": "",
        "object_height": "",
        "object_width": "",
        "origin_datecreated_end": "1963",
        "origin_datecreated_start": "1963",
        "physical_description_extent": [
          "12 1/2 x 18 1/4"
        ],
        "physical_description_material": [
          "Gelatin silver print"
        ],
        "physical_description_technique": [
          "Gelatin silver print"
        ],
        "pid": "bdr:123456",
        "title": "As Demonstrators"
      }]';

    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsondata);
    print_r('<pre>');
    print_r($jsonDecoded);
    print_r('</pre>');
    $fh = fopen('fileout.csv', 'w');
    if (is_array($jsonDecoded)){
      print_r('<-------- line variable output-------->');   
      foreach($jsonDecoded as $line){
            print_r('<pre>'); print_r($line); print_r('</pre>');
        print_r('<-------- data variable output-------->');
        if (is_array($line)||is_object($line)){
          foreach($line as $data){
            fputcsv($fp,$data);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

   fclose($fh);
   print_r('Converted Successfully');
?>
```

I tried looking into most of the similar questions in the stackoverflow but none has a array of my kind so they are not much useful to me.

If I use single foreach I am getting error **Array to String Conversion failed** and **Array** is being printed as value instead of actual data into the csv file.

If I use two foreach I am getting error **fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array string given**

var_dump or print_r result of decoded json is as follows

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [accession_number_original] => 2012.11.45
        [author_birth_date] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1932
            )

        [author_date] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1932
            )

        [author_death_date] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [author_description] => Array
            (
                [0] => American
            )

        [author_display] => Array
            (
                [0] => Day yon
            )

        [author_names_first] => Array
            (
                [0] => Day
            )

        [author_names_last] => Array
            (
                [0] => yon
            )

        [author_names_middle] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [image_height] => 12 1/2
        [image_width] => 18 1/4
        [jp2_image_url] => 
        [location_physical_location] => Art Gallery
        [location_shelf_locator] => Unknown
        [master_image_url] => 
        [note_provenance] => Gift of Gary Ginsberg and Susanna Aaron
        [object_date] => 1963/2010
        [object_depth] => 
        [object_height] => 
        [object_width] => 
        [origin_datecreated_end] => 1963
        [origin_datecreated_start] => 1963
        [physical_description_extent] => Array
            (
                [0] => 12 1/2 x 18 1/4
            )

        [physical_description_material] => Array
            (
                [0] => Gelatin silver print
            )

        [physical_description_technique] => Array
            (
                [0] => Gelatin silver print
            )

        [pid] => bdr:123456
        [title] => As Demonstrators
    )
)
```

Comment: get rid of arrays in first step (converting author_* to string) and then it will not throw array to string error

Comment: @ moped thanks for the comment , can you give little more explination ? Should I manually convert every array without a key value or is there any way to do it .Bear with me I just started to learn php.

Comment: check my answer, ask in comment if something is unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, first step would be to take care of array values, so each line needs to have values converted (it only counts with the format you provided, if there is an array with 2 values, only first will be passed to csv).

Your modified source code:

```
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($jsondata, true); // add true, will handle as associative array    
print_r('<pre>');
print_r($jsonDecoded);
print_r('</pre>');
$fh = fopen('fileout.csv', 'w');
if (is_array($jsonDecoded)) {
  print_r('<-------- line variable output-------->');   
  foreach ($jsonDecoded as $line) {
    // with this foreach, if value is array, replace it with first array value
    foreach ($line as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $line[$key] = $value[0];
        }
    }
    print_r('<pre>'); print_r($line); print_r('</pre>');
    // no need for foreach, as fputcsv expects array, which we already have
    if (is_array($line)) {
      fputcsv($fh,$line);
    }
  }
}
fclose($fh);
print_r('Converted Successfully');
```

Script output after execution:

```
[output of your print_r($jsonDecoded);]

<-------- line variable output-------->

Array
(
    [accession_number_original] => 2012.11.45
    [author_birth_date] => 1932
    [author_date] => 1932
    [author_death_date] => 
    [author_description] => American
    [author_display] => Day yon
    [author_names_first] => Day
    [author_names_last] => yon
    [author_names_middle] => 
    [image_height] => 12 1/2
    [image_width] => 18 1/4
    [jp2_image_url] => 
    [location_physical_location] => Art Gallery
    [location_shelf_locator] => Unknown
    [master_image_url] => 
    [note_provenance] => Gift of Gary Ginsberg and Susanna Aaron
    [object_date] => 1963/2010
    [object_depth] => 
    [object_height] => 
    [object_width] => 
    [origin_datecreated_end] => 1963
    [origin_datecreated_start] => 1963
    [physical_description_extent] => 12 1/2 x 18 1/4
    [physical_description_material] => Gelatin silver print
    [physical_description_technique] => Gelatin silver print
    [pid] => bdr:123456
    [title] => As Demonstrators
)

Converted Successfully
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but nothing is being written into csv file I had permissions to write the file only empty file is being create and also print_r('<pre>'); print_r($line); print_r('</pre>'); doesnt provide any output.

Comment: works fine on my dev, so I assume it's your source, copy/paste only this part after your json string and check the file again

Comment: I've edited my answer so it contains all your source code + needed fixes, be sure to include your `$jsondata` on top of the file

Comment: Thanks @moped I have been struggling to convert it from 3 days second foreach was the issue  thanks a lot it works fine.May be caching issue after clearing browser cache and restarting the server it worked.How to add header to the file ? Is it correct //Creating Header in the file.
 $firstLineKeys = false;
 foreach ($jsonDecoded as $line) {
   if (empty($firstLineKeys)) {
  $firstLineKeys = array_keys($line);
  fputcsv($fh, $firstLineKeys);
 }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Used PHPExcel library that's help me to convert my json file into excel sheet.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

```
                $keyName=array();
                $i=0;
                $current_data=file_get_contents($dir.$excelFileLocation,true);
                $excelFile=fopen($dir."ExcelTojson.xls","w+");
                $array_data=json_decode($current_data,true);
                foreach($array_data as $jsonValue)
                {
                    foreach($jsonValue as $key => $value)
                    {
                        if($i==0)
                        {
                            $keyName[$i]=$key;
                            $i++;
                        }
                        else
                        {  
                            $check=0;
                            for($j=0;$j<count($keyName);$j++)
                            {
                                if($keyName[$j]==$key)
                                {   
                                    $check=1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if($check==0)
                            {
                                $keyName[$i]=$key;
                                $i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $excelSheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($dir."ExcelTojson.xls");
                $excelSheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                $ascii=65;
                for($i=0;$i<count($keyName);$i++)
                {
                    $excelSheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(chr($ascii)."1",stripslashes($keyName[$i]));
                    $ascii+=1;
                }
                $cellValue=2;
                foreach($array_data as $jsonValue)
                {   
                    $ascii=65;
                    foreach($jsonValue as $key => $value)
                    {
                        $excelSheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(chr($ascii).$cellValue,stripslashes($value));
                        $ascii+=1;
                    }
                    $cellValue+=1;
                }

                $filename="ExcelTojson.xls";
                header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
                header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excelSheet, 'Excel5');
                $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but according to readme it cant read json. Am I missing something or do you need more specific information?

Comment: read ur json using json decode and stored into array key in one array and value in other array with same index                                               $excelSheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($dir."ExcelTojson.xls");
     $excelSheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
     $ascii=65;
     for($i=0;$i<count($keyName);$i++)
     {
      $excelSheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue(chr($ascii)."1",stripslashes($keyName[$i]));
      $ascii+=1;
     }

Comment: this is overkill solution + you could've edited your answer, source code is hardly readable in comments ;)

Comment: btw, do you realize that your answer is about XLS not CSV? just to clarify, CSV is not always meant to be used in table processor like Excel

Answer (score -1):

This is my data: I am using Drupal 8. However, it is the same.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [webform_id] => webform
            [sid] => 1
            [name] => Question_1
            [property] => A1
            [delta] => 0
            [value] => 6
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [webform_id] => webform
        [sid] => 1
        [name] => Question_2
        [property] => A2
        [delta] => 0
        [value] => 4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [webform_id] => webform
        [sid] => 1
        [name] => Question_3
        [property] => A3
        [delta] => 0
        [value] => 2
    )
```

)

My function file:

```
public function DisplayData() {
// Fetch the data.

$connection = \Drupal::service('database');
$query = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM {webform}");
$result = $query->fetchAll();

$jsonDecoded = json_decode(json_encode($result), TRUE);
```

//Give our CSV file a name.
   $csvFileName = 'test.csv';

```
//Open file pointer.
$fp = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');

//Loop through the associative array.
foreach($jsonDecoded as $rows){
  //Write the row to the CSV file. fputcsv(file,fields,separator,enclosure)
  foreach ($rows as $key => $value){
    if (is_array($value)){
      $rows[$key] = $value[0];
    }

  }
  if (is_array($rows)) {
    fputcsv($fp, $rows);
    $roka = array_flip($rows);

  }

}
fputcsv($fp, array_merge($roka, $rows));
fclose($fp);

$build = [
  '#theme' => 'webpage',
];
return $build;
```

}

Done---

Comment: You should add a description of the solution you are proposing.

Comment: @Viktor I think this won't work even after second foreach there are still array elements so fputcsv wont accept them.Check [author_birth_date] you will get what I meant.

Comment: Also, this works:  foreach ($jsonDecoded as $row) {
      fputcsv($fp, (array) $row);
    }